# Python simplify HTML table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

is there a good way (e.g. with BeautifulSoup) to simplify an HTML table. I'm using requests to get the table and extract the table with BeautifulSoup but I need the table to go from:

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="bar">Some text<br></br><span class="foobar">foo </span><small class="foo">bar!</small></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

to:

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some text\nfoo bar!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

By a simple way, then I'm thinking of not having to go to every  tag and use *soup.get_text()*.

Comment: Why should `<br><br/>` yield only one `\n`?

Comment: It was supposed to be <br></br>, sorry. I know that it could be <br />. But these are the data that I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the br with newlines:

```
h = """<table>
    <thead></thead>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="bar">Some text<br><br/><span class="foobar">foo </span><small class="foo">bar!</small></a></td>
        </tr>
</table>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

td = soup.select_one("#bar")
td.br.replace_with("\n") 

td.replace_with(td.text)


print(repr(soup))
```

Which gives you:

```
<html><body><table>\n<thead></thead>\n<tr>\n<td>Some text\nfoo bar!</td>\n</tr>\n</table></body></html>
```

Comment: @RadLexus, I am not sure  follow, the point is to change the table?

Comment: Sorry - OPs target was only to get a text not broken by tags. I thought the remaining HTML would still get used as such, but it seems it doesn't matter.

Comment: @RadLexus,no worries, I thought maybe I was missing something.